# UIView transform

Tags: ios, uiview, core-animation, transform, calayer

I got an UIView with 4 views in the corners which will be dragged to create a perspective effect. This is how it looks like in the beggining:

[image]

Once the user drags a view, it will create a transform effect. For example:

[image]

I investigated it and I figured out I have to use CALayer to do that, but I'm still no clearer on how to create this kind of transform on an iPhone. Any help, pointers or example code snippets would be really appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIView perspective](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847851/uiview-perspective)

Answer (score 0):

You should search for CATransform3D. But [this](http://b2cloud.com.au/how-to-guides/ios-perspective-transform) is kind of a good start.